# Film where man wakes up from simulation onboard alien ship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I seem to recall a story where a man begins to question his reality. A woman within the reality reluctantly allows him to see the truth. He wakes up in what looks like a giant spiders den. Then the “woman” is revealed to be a spider like being. I can’t remember what it’s called though.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Is it the same as [Sci-fi movie with one survivor and an organism(?) recreating his memories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220468/sci-fi-movie-with-one-survivor-and-an-organism-recreating-his-memories)? If so it's the Netflix episode [Beyond the Aquila Rift](https://lovedeathrobots.fandom.com/wiki/Beyond_the_Aquila_Rift) based on a story by Alastair Reynolds.

Comment: Welp. I deent need to sleep for the next few weeks anyway. (Welcome to SFF.SE, quasar1229!)

Answer (score 18):

This must surely be [*Beyond the Aquila Rift*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9788496/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), an episode of the TV series Love, Death, and Robots, although with a running time of 17 minutes it is a bit too brief to really be considered a movie. It was based on [a short story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?196029) by Alastair Reynolds of the same name.

The central character is the captain of a spaceship, The Blue Goose, who is awoken from cryosleep to find that his ship has gone far off course. He meets with people to make arrangements to repair his ship, wake the crew, and make his way back home, but he keeps getting fobbed off. Repair estimates keep getting extended, and eventually he realises that he is extremely far from home, way beyond the "Local Bubble" that humans have colonised, out in the Large Magellanic Cloud The people he has been interacting with are just simulations, created by a kindly alien to comfort those who accidentally wind-up in this place. He asks the alien to reveal its true form and find it resembles a giant spider. In the short story, the true appearance of the place he has been living is described thusly:

> in a matriarchal chamber all of its own, something drummed out
> messages to its companions and helpers, stiffly articulated,
> antler-like forelimbs beating against stretched tympana of finely
> veined skin, something that had been waiting here for eternities,
> something that wanted nothing more than to care for the souls of the
> lost.

Comment: Since OP mentions a film, this is undoubtedly the episode of the first series of Netflix's *Love, Death + Robots* that adapted Reynolds' story: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9788496/

Comment: Since OP is asking about a film, I've flipped your answer so that it mentions the show first and the short story second

Comment: @Valorum Gracias amorcín.