# Sci-fi short film involving a tentacled creature which uses illusions to lure unsuspecting spaceships into its web

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Spaceship docks and meets his female rescuer. He falls in love with her and they have sex standing up. The astronaut's backside is fully shown nude.
It turns out that the female created a mirage to entice him where his spaceship was actually caught in a web with other ships, and it ends with her transformed into a hideous creature with tentacles coming out of her cave saying how she knows everything from other words. The camera pans out showing this tangled web of ships.
What is the name of this short?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220468/sci-fi-movie-with-one-survivor-and-an-organism-recreating-his-memories, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265056/film-where-man-wakes-up-from-simulation-onboard-alien-ship

Comment: Yes, almost certainly 'Beyond the Aquila Rift'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sci-fi movie with one survivor and an organism(?) recreating his memories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220468/sci-fi-movie-with-one-survivor-and-an-organism-recreating-his-memories)

Comment: @Binary Worrier - Although the current answer is probably correct, it's premature to flag this thread for closure (on the basis of being a duplicate) until the answer has been confirmed to be correct by the OP.

Comment: @AdeleC - Our [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774) is to not close Story-ID duplicates until we have a positive confirmation from the poster that they're the same property.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I found it quite by accident while scrolling through Netflix It was in the LOVE DEATH + ROBOTS series.

Answer (score 25):

As noted in comments, this is almost certainly *[Beyond the Aquila Rift](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9788496/)*, an episode of the Netflix series *Love, Death & Robots* based on the [short story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?196029) by Alistair Reynolds.

A spaceship makes what should be a standard interstellar jump using a "surge point gate". Something goes wrong, and one of the astronauts, Thom, awakens to find the ship has gone far off course. and is now docked in a space station called Saumlaki Station. An old friend of his, Greta, welcomes him to the station, and as recalled in the question they have sex later that night (and Thom's backside is indeed shown, see below).

He discovers that Greta is really an alien creature who is just using his memories to project an agreeable simulation for him. At his request, she drops the simulation and he sees her real form - a giant spider-like creature with many eyes inhabiting a giant web that traps lost ships.

There is no indication that the alien is in any way malevolent, or luring ships to her. She just seems to be doing her best to care for "all the lost souls that end up here"

[image: Left: Thom's naked backside, Right: the true form of the alien creature]

Comment: Oh look, that kind gentleman is holding that lady up so she can get a better view. Presumably she's looking for her clothes that have somehow gotten lost.